# How do I get the correct path to a folder of an Azure container?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to read files from an Azure storage account. In particular, I'd like to read all files contained in a certain folder, for example:

```
lines = sc.textFile('/path_to_azure_folder/*')
```

I am not quite sure what the path should be. I tried with the URL service blob endpoint, from Azure, followed by the folder path (I tried with both http and https):

```
lines = sc.textFile('https://container_name.blob.core.windows.net/path_to_folder/*')
```

and did not work:

> diagnostics: Application XXXXXX failed 5 times due to AM Container for
>   XXXXXXXX exited with  exitCode: 1   Diagnostics: Exception from
>   container-launch. Container id: XXXXXXXXX Exit code: 1

the URL I provided is the same I'm getting with CyberDuck App, when I click on 'Info'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path should look like this

```
lines = sc.textFile("wasb://containerName@$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/folder_path/*")
```

This should solve your your issue.

Comment: how do I locate the storage account name from within the Azure web interface? I'm not sure what the difference is between container and storage

Comment: you should be able to find it in 'manage.windowsazure.com'. Navigate to Hdinsight and choose the cluster you are working on. Now if you scroll down in Dashboard. You will see all the storage accounts listed there. select the appropriate one.

Comment: sorry for bothering you again. is account name the same as subscription name? if so, how do I handle whitespaces in the name? Thank you,

Comment: Subscription name and storage account name are different. do you have access to 'manage.windowsazure.com'?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to read all the blobs in an Azure Storage account, you might want to look into the tools and libraries we offer for retrieving and manipulating your data. Getting started doc [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-getting-started-guide/).

Hope this is helpful!